# Jquery detect commands/Custom BBcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, bbcode

So I want to be able to detect what a user on my forums writes in a post and change it's CSS accordingly. For example,

```
[hl color:'yellow']example test[/hl]
```

should apply a hightlight to the text:

```
style="background-color: yellow"
```

I want the jQuery code to detect `[hl color:` if successful, save the value between the `' '` in a variable then test for the remaining `]`. I then want it to apply `style="background-color: " + var` to the text after the `]` and before the `[/hl]`

Thanks in advanced.

Current unworking code:

```
$('.post').each(function() {   
  if($(this:contains('[hl color:'))) {
    var txt = [I have no idea];
    $(select the text in between tags).attr('style', 'background-color:' + txt);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please show some effort? what have you done on the so-called requested jQuery code? If there are any, please attach to ur question

Comment: ok, happy? added jquery

Comment: Dont be unhappy with this, as this is the right way of asking question here, not my personal opinion. If you dont like to receive downvotes, thats the only way. BTW its up to u

Comment: I really have no idea how to do it, the reason I cam here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: Use a library

There are already plenty of JavaScript libraries that parse BBCode. [This one](https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser) looks promising, and is extensible so that you can add your own tags. You could also consider doing the parsing on the server side (in PHP or whatever you are using) using a library there (like [jBBCode](http://jbbcode.com/) for PHP).

## Option 2: Do it yourself

No actual jQuery is needed for this. Instead, for simple tags regex does the trick:

```
function bbcodeToHTML(bbcode) {
  return bbcode.replace(
           /\[\s*hl\s*color\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*\](.*?)\[\s*\/\s*hl\s*\]/gi,
           '<span style="background-color:$1;">$2</span>'
         );
}
```

So what does this regex do?

- `\[\s*hl\s*color\s*:\s*`: Literal `[`, then any number of whitespaces, then `color`, then any number of whitespaces, then literal `:`, then any number of whitespaces.
- `(.*?)`: Captures (as `$1`) any characters lazily. This means that it tries to match as few characters as possible.
- `\s*\]`: Ends the opening tag.
- `(.*?)`: Same as above, but captures as `$2`
- `\[\s*\/\s*hl\s*\]`: Ending tag, with any number of whitespaces thrown in.
- `g`: Global flag. Replaces all matches and do not stop after first.
- `i`: Case insensitive flat. Match both `HL` and `hl`.

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/fZ1nG0/1).

## Replacing the content of forum posts

Now you will need som jQuery. I will assume that the elements that contain forum posts in BBCode that you want replaced with HTML all have a class named `post` so that they can be identified. Then this code would do the job:

```
//Itterate over all forum posts.
jQuery('.post').each(function() {

    //Get a reference to the current post.
    currentPost = jQuery(this);

    //Get the content ant turn it into HTML.
    postHTML = bbcodeToHTML(currentPost.html());

    //Put the html into the post.
    currentPost.html(postHTML);

});
```

For more info on jQuery, you can always check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: So how do I use this for what I want. I've never encountered regex before

Comment: I've rewritten it as a function you can use. Whenever you have a variable with BBCode (or rather your one tag subset of it) call that function to get it as HTML. I don't know where you get the BBCode from or where you want to put the HTML, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: I am guessing here, but do you want it to run whenever a forum page is viewed, and replace the content of all posts?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want

Comment: Please consider updating your question to more clearly reflect that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: works! only 1 problem though, any text after the hl tag is put on a new line

Comment: nvm, just changed it from div to span

Comment: Glad it worked. If the answer was helpful, please check the checkbox to indicate that you accept it.

Comment: You are right that `<span>` is better than `<div>` - I updated my answer.